# C++ Vector2D class operations

Tags: c++, math, vector, coordinates

I have a class called Vec2D to handle 2d vector manipulation.

```
   Vec2D pos1 = Vec2D( 100, 100 );
   Vec2D pos2 = Vec2D( 100, 100 );
```

I have operators overloaded so arithmetic can be simpler. Thus I can do the following:

```
Vec2D difference = pos1-pos2;
float distance = difference .magnitude();
```

I want to know **is it possible to do arithmetic like this with my class?:**

```
float distance = (pos1-pos2).magnitude();
```

I tried compiling but it gives me weird errors such as "Class Vec2D has no iterators..."
The only reason I thought out that would explain this is the fact that there is no class existing in the result?

Comment: Shouldn't that be float distance = (pos1-pos2).magnitude()?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer without knowing how you defined `operator-`? Anyway, it's certainly possible, and a popular way to use C++. The [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) is one very nice implementation of vectors and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is probably the way you implemented the `-` operator. The prototype should be:

```
Vec2D operator- (const Vec2D &rhs) const
```

or outside of class

```
Vec2D operator- ( const Vec2D& v1, const Vec2D& v2 )
```

How are your operators declared? Especially -- what is the operations return type?

Comment: Non-member is better: the same conversions are applicable to the left and right operands. Member leads to asymmetry which can cause tricky bugs. Also, it's preferred to pass one operand of the non-member by value, then modify and return it, to help the compiler eliminate copies.

Comment: Well I do have the function return Vec2D but it is a friend function. Would that make any difference?

Comment: inline Vec2D operator+( const Vec2D& rhs )const{...  that fixed it. Thanks